# How can I send the client data, along with a served Html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, express

I'm building a basic web app.

I'm serving the client an Html page that references some `.js` files. The attached script needs to manipulate the DOM according to some data (e.g., a username). This data is stored in the server.

The client can either request the data from the server, which seems odd since data (an Html file) just arrived from the server, or it can receive the data along with the served file.

So in Node.js and Express, how can I send the client data along with the served file? Is the query-string the best option? If so, how do I create a query string to send along with the page? If not, what are the other options?

Also, is the option of the client-script simply requesting the information from the server a common approach? It seems odd but it is okay?

Comment: If you don't want to go with AJAX, you should be able to pass whatever data you want by in-lining an object in a `<script>` tag within your initial HTML response.

Comment: It's not unusual to fetch html templates and json data separately and then render the final html with the json data client-side.

Comment: Express has routing. You can use Jade to render HTML templates with data baked in based on the user's route. You should do some research on it.

Comment: It is common if you are building a Single Page Application. But if you are serving each page I would reccomend using @MaxBaldwin 's approach. Otherwise if you don't want to use a JST, you can use Eclecticist 's approach and inline it.. Personally (Subjectively) If SPA wasn't an option, I would use JADE or Handlebars and compile the page from a template.

Comment: I have only used Handlebars on the front end, but if you can use it with Node server side, I would pick that over Jade.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin So let me see if I understand: when data needs to be integrated dynamically in a page, there are two options - either serve the page to the client, have the client request the data from the server and integrate it inside, or have the server put the data programatically in the page using a templating engine. And the second approach is the more professional one. Am I correct?

Comment: @AvivCohn Correct. The second one is more professional, faster and more secure.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Great so I'll look into a templating engine. Is Jade good?

Comment: @AvivCohn, yeah Jade is good. Do some research and see which template engine will work best for you. There is Jade, Handlebars, EJS. Jade also runs hand in hand with Stylus, which is a CSS precomplier. If you want to go crazy you could use Less as well and make your whole app server side. Whatever pops your toast